# Terminate remote process when backgrounded ssh session is terminated

Tags: ssh, bash, remote, terminal, shell-scripting

So right now I have a bash script that runs a command on a remote machine using ssh. The machine running the bash script is a Linux machine and the remote machine is a Windows machine running cygwin. The bash script contains the following lines

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -i key.pem user@ip "command1" &
# some other commands here, not included because they're not relevant to question
wait
```

*command1* is a long-running process. Currently when I Ctrl-C out of my bash script before wait completes, *command1* is still running on the remote machine. It essentially becomes detached and uncontrollable. I want it to terminate when I Ctrl-C, otherwise the remote machine will be littered with many instances of command1 if I constantly terminate my script prematurely. **Note** the background & is necessary because I want to run other commands while that command is running.

I've tried several methods already

1. Add the "-t -t" option for pseudo-terminal
2. Added the below line in the hopes of passing SIGINT to my ssh sessions

   ```
   trap 'kill -INT -$$' SIGINT
   ```

   I also did a variation of the trap command where I got a list of child PIDs and iterated through it killing each one. That didn't work either. SIGHUP also did not work.

So far the only way I've gotten *command1* to terminate is if I just run the ssh command

```
ssh -t -i key.pem user@ip "command1"
```

without backgrounding it and type Ctrl-C in the same terminal. It doesn't even work if I send a SIGINT or SIGHUP from another terminal.

What is the correct way to terminate remote commands via backgrounded ssh?

**NOTE** This only happens when the remote machine is a cygwin environment.

Comment: Instead of `wait`ing at the end of your script, why don't you just bring ssh back into the foreground after those other commands are complete?  (ie `fg`)

Comment: It's also possible that I terminate before I reach the wait. Some of the other commands do take time to do. Even if I replace the wait with a fg, there's a possibility that it won't get there.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function killcommand1() {
    ssh -i key.pem user@ip 'kill `cat/tmp/command1_pid`'
}

trap "killcommand1" SIGINT

ssh -i key.pem user@ip 'command1 & echo $! > /tmp/command1_pid' &
# other commands
wait
```

This worked for me going from one Linux system to another, and unfortunately I don't have a cygwin installation available, but this way of sending the kill command could work anyway.